# How to fetch data from multiple tables with one SQL query in Hanami?

Tags: ruby, hanami, ruby-object-mapper

I have Hanami models `User` and `UserInfo` that have `has_one` association.

Repositories look the following:

```
class UserInfoRepository < Hanami::Repository
end

class UserRepository < Hanami::Repository
  associations do
    has_one :user_info
  end
end
```

Question: who can I join and load both tables with one query? (I am looking for something similar to Rails' `includes`).

So far I've tried

```
def users_with_info
  users.join(:user_info)
end
```

It does the join, but does not select columns from `user_infos` table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hanami but it looks like it uses `rom-repository` and `sequel` under the scenes. Something like `aggregate(:user_info)` should work according to http://api.rom-rb.org/rom/ROM/Repository/Root#aggregate-instance_method let me know if this helps so i can make it the answer

Comment: Thanks. `aggregate` is quite similar to what I am trying to achieve: it returns the same set of data I am trying to obtain, but it does 2 request:
- first to fetch all `users`
- second to fetch all `user_infos` with condition `user_id IN (1,2,3,4, 5 ...)`. It just enumerates ids of all fetched users in SQL query.

Comment: I wonder if performing the join and then the aggregate explicitly would work. I'm sorry I don't have much knowledge of the gems. Just vaguely looked at the docs

Answer (score 2):

When you fetch data via a Repository in Hanami the result set is mapped into entities.
By default the `UserRepository` will map to the `User` entity. I'm guessing that that entity does not have attributes for the columns from `user_info`.

What you need to do is create an Entity that can contain the data that you want to fetch from the database and then call `.as(ThatEntityYouCreated)` on the result set. E.g.,

```
def users_with_info
  users.join(:user_info).map_to(UserWithInfo)
end
```

If you do not want to create an Entity and just want to get a plain hash, you can do this:

```
users.join(:user_info).map.to_a
```

However, I consider this to be a crutch. You should not return Hashes from your Repository methods.

Answer (score 1):

I believe we faced this exact issue with a teammate of mine on one of our Hanami project, and this is **[how we solved it](https://github.com/nfilzi/housing-list/blob/master/lib/housing_list/repositories/housing_repository.rb#L50).**

We basically bypassed Hanami repository, going straight to the underlying ROM relation, using **[`ROM::Relation#wrap`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rom-rb/rom/ROM%2FRelation:wrap)** in order to get our `User` entity joined with the entity of interest.

Let met know if it helped you, or if you need more details. Cheers!